# Cut part of video with ffmpeg with both sync and quality?

Tags: audio, video, sync, ffmpeg

How to cut part of video with `ffmpeg` without any problems?

The following command

```
ffmpeg -i <infile> -ss <starttime> -to <endtime> -vcodec copy -acodec copy <outfile>
```

will most probably loose audio-video synchronization.

And the following command

```
ffmpeg -i <infile> -ss <starttime> -to <endtime> <outfile>
```

will most probably loose quality since recoding.

I need to conserve both: syncing and quality. The goal is: cut only.

The time of conversion stage does not matter.

Is it possible to achieve with `ffmpeg`?

Comment: Please include the complete ffmpeg console outputs.

Comment: I use -t <endtime> (Not -to which is up to position). I have never experienced out-sync issues. You first command ought to work fine unless there are other issues. So may be you can share what actually went wrong.